# Center 3 images in a row on a simple html page with few other elements

Tags: html, image, gallery, center

I am trying to center an image gallery of 3 images in a row on a simple web page with few other elements. Everything should be centered on the page. But the image gallery displays vertically instead of in a row. And it aligns left instead of center.

I used the image gallery code I found on this website. I've also tried a few other things that are now commented out in my code.

You may view the page and the code at this url:
http://www.sherryhutson.com/splash4.html

I want the 3 images to display in a row. I want that row to be centered on the web page (to match the other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

because the images are wrapped around a div and a div adds a line break, you will need to add `display: inline-block` to the css selector `div.gallery`

now, you can add a `text-align:center` to the container element, or add a wrapper
container to you images, and then use the css rule i mentioned previously to align to the center.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and post my results.

Comment: Yes, that worked and solved my problem. Thank you very much!